# IBM Websphere MQ: Failing to authorize 'mqadmin'

Tags: ibm-mq

Unable to give the permission '**chg**' to the `SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE`. We tried giving using `setmqaut` with `mqm` super user access but no luck! Currently it is flooding our `AMQERR*` error logs. Need your help on this.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the error.

Comment: Any reason you did not accept or upvote the answer provided by Morag?

Answer (score 1):

The `SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE` is very restricted. This is because it holds the data that is your authority rules. You cannot give `chg` permission to a non-privileged user ID and a privileged user ID already has the ability to change.

[IBM Knowledge Center says](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014080_.htm):-

> Authorization data is stored on a local queue called SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE. Access to this queue is restricted to users in the mqm group, and additionally on Windows, to users in the Administrators group, and users logged in with the SYSTEM ID. User access to the queue cannot be changed.

If you need to make a change to this queue (you don't say why), then you can only do it using a privileged user id, e.g. a member of the mqm group.